# Why is yibum no longer done?

Tags: marriage, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

The prevailing practice is to always to chalitzah and not to do yobum. Why avoid doing yibum? From the description of the chumash chalitzah at best serms like the lesser option so why avoid the mitzvah of yibum?

Comment: note that this differs between communities.

Comment: "The prevailing practice is to always to chalitzah and not to do yobum" Huh? On what basis do you say that? That doesn't seem true

Comment: @DoubleAA proving this is not true could be an answer